# Electromagnetic wave going through a square frame

Tags: electromagnetism, waves

I would like some help on the following questions :

1. How to orient the square frame of conducting wire to maximize the power of the wave passing through it? How is the average power of the wave passing through the frame expressed?
2. The surface area of the square frame is much smaller than the wavelength. Justify that this property allows us to neglect the spatial dependence of the electromagnetic wave in a region of space on the order of the size of the frame. By neglecting the spatial dependence of the wave in this region, how should the frame be oriented to maximize the magnetic flux of the wave through the frame?

Some informations :
It is a planar monochromatic wave
There's also written that the black part and the grey part are both equal to S/2 (with S the surface).

for 1), my first assumption was that I had to put the square perpendicular to the poynting vector and find out the power going through with $P=\int\int \vec{\pi}.\vec{dS}$

But now I'm thinking otherwise and maybe I should put the square in the direction of $\vec E$

And then for 2), I would like some guidance on how to justify the neglection of spatial dependence

Thanks in advance !

[image: Text]

Comment: You seem to be asking about a "small loop antenna". There is much literature on this. Start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_antenna

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A small loop, small relative to the wavelength, is a magnetic dipole. You should orient the square frame (left diagram), therefore, so that its plane be *perpendicular* to the magnetic field. This is because a planar loop, here a square loop, is naturally responsive to a linear polarization in which the vector of the electric field lies in the plane of the loop and the magnetic field of it perpendicular to it.
The loop in the right hand figure will not likely generate anything measurable because it is a magnetic quadrupole, and a plane wave will excite two counter flowing currents of about equal size. If the half loops were placed a half wavelength apart then it may act as pair of properly phased dipoles.

Comment: Can you explain me why it is a magnetic dipole ? And also you told me that I had to orientate it so that the sides are perpendicular to B but doesn't it lose some (because of B being perpendicular)?

Comment: In a small loop the current is uniform and it *is* a magnetic dipole, check the distribution of its magnetic field https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dipole#/media/File:VFPt_dipole_magnetic3.svg and here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dipole In a small loop the current is uniform!

Comment: So the electric field induces a flow of the electrons in the wire thus creating a magnetic field around the loop ?

Comment: it is probably better to think of it as that the time varying magnetic flux induces the current in the loop, or that the time varying current in the loop induces a time varying magnetic field distributed as one of a magnetic dipole.